# THREE.Object3D or scene or other class provide any tags or methods that I can detected my object has been changed？

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using three.js render obj model in browser.
Here is my logic of program：

```
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
        render(scene, camera);
    }

    function render(scene, camera){
        scene.traverse(function(object) {
                     scene = setLODDistance(scene, thresHold);
            });
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

animate();
```

function setLODDistance will return a scene object which has been calculated by LOD.

but I do not want to call this function every fps, I just want to call it after my object in browser been translated or rotated or scaling.

so in THREE.Object3D or scene or other class provide any tags or methods that I can detected my object has been changed(translated or rotated or scaling) ??

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Object.watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), poly fill here: [link](https://gist.github.com/adriengibrat/b0ee333dc1b058a22b66).